# Can't populate listview from firebase database but toast works

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a listview realtime from my firebase database. The data  uploads to database without any issues and a toast which displays the newly added data also works. But I could not get the listview to work. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView list;
private Button btnadd;
private EditText ettext;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list=findViewById(R.id.liston);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    btnadd=findViewById(R.id.button);
    ettext=findViewById(R.id.ed);


    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabase.push().setValue(ettext.getText().toString());
        }
    });




    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String string =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(string);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Name: " + dataSnapshot.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String string =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.remove(string);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

The updation of the database also happens from within the app using an "edittext" and a button.

Comment: What does it mean, you can't get the listview to work? Is there an error? Does it show anything?...

Comment: @Yuliwee Sorry if I wasn't being clear. The list view doesn't populate with the data entered. It remains empty

Comment: I believe adapter is null here `list.setAdapter(adapter);` because you create it afterwards.